# Show that $\Vert A\Vert= \sigma_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in R^{n\times n}$ with full SVD $U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal $n\times n$ matrices and $\Sigma$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with entries $\sigma_1 \geq\cdots\geq \sigma_n \geq 0$.

Show that $\Vert A\Vert=\sigma_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that
$$
\|A^*A\|=\sup _{\|x\|=1}\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle=\|A\|^2.$$
Here it will be useful that $A^*A$ is self-adjoint, so you can assume it is diagonal.

Comment: I see your point. By Self-Adjoint do you mean symmetric? (given that all entries of A are real)?

Comment: In this case, yes. Self-adjointedness is the property for complex matrices corresponding to symmetry for real matrices. Basically, real and symmetric implies self-adjoint, but not the other way around.